# convert string to ISO date time in nodejs

Tags: node.js, datetime, toisostring

Convert this date into ISO format in nodejs

```
     created_at="September 17th 2019, 16:50:17.000";  
     let new_time = new Date(created_at);
     created_at = new_time.toISOString();
     console.log(created_at);
```

Output: Invalid Date

Exacting output is in ISO format. like this 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z

Comment: first you'll need to parse date before converting it to ISO string. Something like 17/09/2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) is a library which you can use to get the output and do some advanced operations with date and timezones.
Below is the code to get expected output.

```
 var moment = require('moment')

 created_at="September 17th 2019, 16:50:17.000";  
 let new_time = moment("September 17th 2019, 16:50:17.000", "MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss:SSS");
 created_at = new_time.toISOString();
 console.log(created_at);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to pass the date string in below format in order to convert it to ISO date:

```
var date1 = "September 17 2019, 16:50:17.000";
let new_date = new Date(date1);
console.log(new_date);
console.log(new_date.toISOString());
```