# How to prevent changes on timestamp when convert from string to ISODate Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have a date in (yyyy-mm-dd) format, i want to get start and end date with timestamps and ISO format, i can concat date and timestamp but i want it in date type not in string,

```
let date = "2020-09-11";
```

Expected result should be,

```
startDate = 2020-09-11T00:00:00.000Z
endDate = 2020-09-11T23:59:59.000Z
```

The start date is correct, The end date is not correct, it gives different time stamp, `18:29:59.000Z` when i set it to `setHours(23,59,59)`,

```
let startDate = new Date(date);
console.log(startDate);
// output: 2020-09-11T00:00:00.000Z

let endDate = new Date(new Date(date).setHours(23,59,59)); 
console.log(endDate);
// output: 2020-09-11T18:29:59.000Z
```

I looked at this question [convert string to ISO date time in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130131/convert-string-to-iso-date-time-in-nodejs), but this does not help me, i don't want to use `moment`,

Am i doing wrong to convert dates? i am using nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `setUTCHours()`

> The `setUTCHours()` method sets the hour for a specified date according to universal time

```js
let date = new Date()
let startDate = new Date(new Date(date).setUTCHours(0,0,0));
let endDate = new Date(new Date(date).setUTCHours(23,59,59));

console.log(startDate);
console.log(endDate);
```

Comment: Forgot to zero the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the postfix without conversion to a local date.

```js
let date = "2020-09-11",
    startDate = date + 'T00:00:00.000Z',
    endDate = date + 'T23:59:59.000Z';

console.log(startDate);
console.log(endDate);
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, i know that but i want it in Date type, not in string, because want to pass in database.